# Group recursively adjacent tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping

I have an unsorted list of integer tuples such as:

```
a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]
```

I am trying to find a way to group up the "recursively adjacent" tuples. "Adjacent" are the tuples with Manhattan distance of 1. By "recursively" we means that if A tuple is adjacent to B and B is adjacent to C, then A, B and C should end up in the same group.

The function that returns the Manhattan distance is this:

```
def Manhattan(tuple1, tuple2):
    return abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1])
```

The expected result is:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)], [(4, 4), (4, 5)], [(8, 8), (8, 9)]
```

In this example (1, 1) is adjacent to (2, 1) and (2, 1) to (3, 1) so these three should be grouped up together.

The order doesn't matter so this result is equivalent:

```
[(3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)], [(4, 4), (4, 5)], [(8, 9), (8, 8)]
```

Are there any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: `itertools.product(a, repeat=2)` sounds like a way to start, even if perhaps not the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: `Manhattan((3, 1), (1,1))` returns `2` (not `1`)- so why are they grouped?

Comment: @Chris_Rands maybe my description is not correct. What I need is all the tuples that are interconnected with distance 1. In our case the (1,1) is connected with (2,1) and (2,1) with (3,1) so they have to be in the same group. I need a better description.

Comment: @Chris_Rands this is not an equivalence relation, but still a well defined problem. They are in the same group because both have manhattan distance 1 to the point (2,1)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have edited the description to make clear the recusive relationship of the tuples within each group.

Comment: This sounds like a "reachability problem" where you keep only edges of weight 1.

Comment: can there be duplicate tuples? can you provide a few more test cases with example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Chris_Rands in my case they don't.

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta It is exactly a reachability problem. I am trying to find a way to convert the adjacent empty spaces into emtpy spaced rooms.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the word you're looking for is "transitively", not "recursively".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a somewhat [UnionFind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) approach, iterating all 1-distanced pairs and "Unifying" their groups:

```py
from itertools import groupby, product


def Manhattan(tuple1, tuple2):
    return abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1])


a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]

tuple_pairs_with_distance_1 = [sorted(pair) for pair in product(a, repeat=2) if Manhattan(*pair) == 1]

result_dict = {t: {t} for t in a}
for t1, t2 in tuple_pairs_with_distance_1:
    # "Unify" these tuple's groups
    result_dict[t1] |= result_dict[t2]
    result_dict[t2] = result_dict[t1]

result = [[*next(g)] for k, g in groupby(sorted(result_dict.values(), key=id), id)]
print(result)
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the solution since it works correct even with @flornquacke's example: a = [(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1)]. It is a bit slow but gives correct results in more cases.

Comment: @thanos.a This solution is O(n^2) because product(a, repeat=2) is basically a nested for loop. Since you want the Manhattan distance of exactly 1, it can be O(n) by checking only the 4 neighbors. E.g. for (1, 1), you only need to check whether (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1) are in the set of points, if yes, you found a pair.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly.

```
a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]
a = sorted(a)
def Manhattan(tuple1, tuple2):
    return abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1])


result = [set()]
l = len(a)
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if not i+1 >= l:
        if Manhattan(v, a[i+1]) ==1:
            result[-1].add(v)
            result[-1].add(a[i+1])
        else:
            result.append(set())
            result[-1].add(a[i+1])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)}, {(4, 5), (4, 4)}, {(8, 9), (8, 8)}]
```

Comment: minor thing, you will miss groups of length 1, e.g for `a = [(1, 1), (1,2), (1,3), (9,9)]`, I suggested an edit.

Comment: @Rekesh I was wondering if it would be faster using enumerate(iterable, start=1), ommiting the if not i=1 > = l and comparing the v against the previous value instead of next. I will check it and let you know.

Comment: @Rakesh I 've compared the performance of this solution against the others on a 2500 tuple problem and it has finished incomperably faster.

Comment: This doesn't work for some inputs, such as `a = [(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1)]`.

Comment: @flornquake thats true.. ordering might cause tuples of distance 1 to appear further than one apart in the list

Answer (score 2):

A completely different, maybe less efficient but certainly interesting approach, would be with a graph theoretic formulation. You can view this problem as finding all connected components of a graph where two vertices are connected whenever the Manhattan distance is one. Crudely written, you could do :

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]
n = len(a)
G.add_nodes_from(a)

# Generate edges
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if Manhattan(a[i],a[j]) == 1:
            G.add_edge(a[i], a[j])

# Find components
components = nx.connected_components(G)
for x in components:
    print(x)
```

which spits out

```
{(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)}
{(4, 5), (4, 4)}
{(8, 9), (8, 8)}
```

Comment: I am testing @flornquacke's solution and it seems that this doesn't work for his example a = [(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1)] wihch gives {(1, 1), (2, 1)}
{(1, 3)}

Comment: @thanos.a which is what it should give, no? (1,1) and (2,1) are in Manhattan distance 1, while (1,3) has distance 2 to the former and 3 to the latter. Its the accepted answer that doesnt work, I believe.

Comment: @bannana You are right. I will retest and come back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach :

```
from itertools import permutations as p
from itertools import chain
a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]
def Manhattan(tuple1, tuple2):
    return (abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1]))==1
l = [list(i) for i in p(a,2) if Manhattan(i[0], i[1])]
ll = set(chain.from_iterable(l))
for each in ll:
    components = [x for x in l if each in x]
    for i in components:
        l.remove(i)
    l += [list(set(chain.from_iterable(components)))]
```

**Output** :

```
# l becomes
[[(4, 5), (4, 4)], [(8, 9), (8, 8)], [(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]]
```

Comment: the output I get is [[(4, 5), (3, 1), (4, 4), (2, 1), (8, 9), (8, 8), (1, 1)]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def Manhattan(tuple1, tuple2):
   return abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1])

a = [(1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 5), (8, 8), (4, 4), (8, 9), (2, 1)]
```

---

```
def group(d, c = [], flag = False):
   _c, new_c = [i for i in a if Manhattan(d, i) == 1 and i not in c], []
   for i in _c:
      new_c.extend([j for k in group(i, c = _c+c+[i], flag=True) for j in k])
   yield set([d]+_c+new_c)
   _start = [i for i in a if i not in _c+new_c+c]
   yield from [] if flag or not _start else group(_start[0], _c+new_c+c+[_start[0]])

print(list(group(a[0], [a[0]])))
```

Output:

```
[{(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)}, {(4, 5), (4, 4)}, {(8, 9), (8, 8)}]
```

Comment: I have tested this solution in my real problem and it doesn't finish. I get the error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print(list(group(a[0], [a[0]])))
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 7, in group
...
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
...
    _c, new_c = [i for i in a if Manhattan(d, i) == 1 and i not in c], []
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 2, in Manhattan
    return abs(tuple1[0] - tuple2[0]) + abs(tuple1[1] - tuple2[1])
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object